# \usepackage{lmodern} changes textcomp's \textbullet and \textopenbullet in a beamer file

Tags: beamer, fonts, latin-modern, textcomp

I use `\textbullet` and `\textopenbullet` (from textcomp package) in a beamer file.
It gives just what I expect:

[image]

However, when I add the lmodern package in the preamble (to avoid font warnings and discrepancies), it changes into some ugly squares:

[image]

Is it possible to use lmodern AND get nice bullets?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{MWE}
\textbullet\textopenbullet
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out that:

- if you put `lmodern` in the options of `beamer`, you get the nice bullets (`\documentclass[10pt,lmodern]{beamer}`)
- if you include the `lmodern` package, you get ugly squares (`\usepackage{lmodern}`)

I don't know why.

```
\documentclass[10pt,lmodern]{beamer}
%\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

%\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{MWE}
\textbullet\textopenbullet
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure giving `lmodern` as an option to beamer does not break features of the package? For instance, I loaded `lmodern` to get `\textsc`; this no longer works when given as an option to beamer.

Comment: Yes, it seems using it as an option instead including the package is not equivalent. I did not bother to investigate, though, since my problem was resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Put `\usefonttheme{serif}` in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}    
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{MWE}
\textbullet\textopenbullet
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't that change the font theme to serif for the whole document? I suppose sans serif is the default.

Answer (score 2):

For filled bullets I'd use `$\bullet$`

For itemize environment `\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{$\bullet$}`

Comment: Yes, for filled bullets $\bullets$ can be used, and for open bullets $\circ$. But to avoid unnecessary spacing, you have to write e.g. $\bullet$$\circ$$\circ$ instead of $\bullet\circ\circ$. Not as clear a code as I'd like, but working nonetheless!